# Pandas Join 3 dfs

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 dfs that I'm not sure how to merge.

df1:

```
ID Name XCount
111 aaa 3
222 bbb 2
333 ccc 3
```

df2:

```
ID Name YCount
111 abc 3
222 bbb 2
444 ddd 1
```

df3:

```
ID Name YCount 
111 aaa 2
222 bbb 3
555 eee 4
```

Goal:

```
ID Name XCount YCount Zcount
111 aaa 3 NA 2
111 abc NA 3 NA
222 bbb 2 2 3
333 ccc 2 NA NA
444 ddd NA 1 NA
555 eee NA NA 4
```

I tried to concat but the ID and Name fields wouldn't match.

Thanks!!!

Comment: concat should work. show us your code.

Comment: I take that back. Would need to add a groupby too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use merge

```
df1.merge(df2, on = ['ID', 'Name'],how = 'outer').merge(df3,  on = ['ID', 'Name'], how = 'outer')

    ID  Name    XCount  YCount_x    YCount_y
0   111 aaa     3.0     NaN         2.0
1   222 bbb     2.0     2.0         3.0
2   333 ccc     3.0     NaN         NaN
3   111 abc     NaN     3.0         NaN
4   444 ddd     NaN     1.0         NaN
5   555 eee     NaN     NaN         4
```

Comment: Thanks! After I did the merge I got ID_x Name_x ID_y Name_y.  Is there a way to avoid those?

Comment: You shouldn't, did you use on = ['ID', 'Name']?

Comment: Yes.  I got that problem several times whenever I try to merge it's not a big deal just annoying.

Comment: You get that only in you are merging two datasets with duplicate column names. Its pandas way of telling you that one ID is from dataframe x while the other is from y. You shouldn't get that if you are merging on ID and Name. You are getting that for YCount becase both the dfs have column YCount and we are not merging on that column so its getting duplicated

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with concat and groupby: `df = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(i) for i in (data1,data2,data3)).groupby(['ID','Name']).sum().reset_index()`. Full example below:

Concat would put the things on top of each other.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'ID': {0: 111, 1: 222, 2: 333},
 'Name': {0: 'aaa', 1: 'bbb', 2: 'ccc'},
 'XCount': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 3}}

data2 = {'ID': {0: 111, 1: 222, 2: 444},
 'Name': {0: 'abc', 1: 'bbb', 2: 'ddd'},
 'YCount': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1}}

data3 = {'ID': {0: 111, 1: 222, 2: 555},
 'Name': {0: 'aaa', 1: 'bbb', 2: 'eee'},
 'ZCount': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4}}

df = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(i) for i in (data1,data2,data3))
```

print(df) returns:

```
    ID Name  XCount  YCount  ZCount
0  111  aaa     3.0     NaN     NaN
1  222  bbb     2.0     NaN     NaN
2  333  ccc     3.0     NaN     NaN
0  111  abc     NaN     3.0     NaN
1  222  bbb     NaN     2.0     NaN
2  444  ddd     NaN     1.0     NaN
0  111  aaa     NaN     NaN     2.0
1  222  bbb     NaN     NaN     3.0
2  555  eee     NaN     NaN     4.0
```

If we now perform a groupby:

```
df.groupby(['ID','Name']).sum().reset_index()
```

We get:

```
    ID Name  XCount  YCount  ZCount
0  111  aaa     3.0     NaN     2.0
1  111  abc     NaN     3.0     NaN
2  222  bbb     2.0     2.0     3.0
3  333  ccc     3.0     NaN     NaN
4  444  ddd     NaN     1.0     NaN
5  555  eee     NaN     NaN     4.0
```

Comment: Cool!  I want to ask an additional question.  Can I get the count and mean for the ID based on ID?

Comment: @TylerNG maybe better to ask a new question and describe expected output.